# Download .vhd image from Azure to local machine, and upload to another Azure account

Tags: powershell, azure, cloud, virtual-machine, azure-storage

I'd like to download a VM image to my local machine, so I can use it locally and upload it to another credential of Azure. I know that there is blob URL but wget didn't help to download it, because it occurs

```
<Error>
<Code>ResourceNotFound</Code>
<Message>
The specified resource does not exist. RequestId:e7ffa746-b35c-44f3-a354-af2abfdaa823 Time:2012-09-27T18:07:00.3196644Z
</Message>
</Error>
```

Any ideas? I also tried to migrate a VM image from one Azure account to another using Azure CMDLets, but got trouble because CMDLets doesn't work properly in multiple credentials.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've finally found out an open source explorer for Azure Storage. (despite Cloud Storage Studio is great, but it's commercial version.)

http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/

It can have multiple credentials and has several functions to manage files (copy, rename, delete, and download)

Once I download vhd on my local machine, I can upload it to another place by using

```
azure vm disk upload
```

on Azure powershell.

Comment: Disclosure - I'm one of the devs on Cerebrata tools :). One thing you may want to keep in mind when supporting the tooling is that when it comes to page blob, please ensure that it supports sparse downloading i.e. download only the non-zero bytes from the page blob instead of whole page blob. I know that Cloud Storage Studio does that.

Answer (score 38):

From the Windows Azure Portal you can easily download the VHD. Just navigate to STORAGE and then the storage account in which your virtual disk is created. Select CONTAINERS (at the top), open the container named "vhds". Just click the vhd you want and select DOWNLOAD (at the bottom of the page).

I hope this helps.

Comment: man, I've spent hours messing with these storage explorers and nothing worked, whereas I could just click in the portal. Duh.

Comment: this is the surest and simplest way

Comment: For some reason, when I click over CONTAINERS, it keeps "loading", I just have 2 vhds, it shouldn´t be so hard to load... bad luck to me, but your answer I guess is the right one. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The reason you're getting this error is because the blob is in a private blob container. You could do a few things:

1. Either make the blob container publicly accessible.
2. Or create a shared access signature with read permission and use that for downloading the blob.

If you wish to migrate blob to another storage account and you wish to use a tool, may I suggest you use Cloud Storage Studio (http://www.cerebrata.com/Products/CloudStorageStudio). Using this tool you can also download the VHD. Also do take a look at this blog post as well: http://www.biztalkgurus.com/biztalk_server/biztalk_blogs/b/biztalk/archive/2012/09/26/windows-azure-virtual-hard-disk-blob-storage-cross-account-copy-lease-break-and-management-tool.aspx.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you tell us how to achieve that by using option (1)? I could not find how to do that neither in old azure console (manage.windowsazure.com) nor in the new one (portal.azure.com).

Comment: Never mind! I found it. If anybody needs this, here are the steps (1) go to the old azure portal in https://manage.windowsazure.com (2) Click on storage and click on your storage (3) Click on 'Containers' on the top, select a container and click Edit, at the bottom. (4) Change the access to 'Public Container'. Another interesting link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-manage-access-to-resources/

Answer (score 4):

If you prefere a scripting solution I would suggest the Microsoft Azure PowerShell CmdLets:
http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9811175&clcid=0x407

By using the "-NumberOfThreads 4" option you could increase the throughput. By using "Add-AzureAccount" and "Select-AzureSubscription" you could switch between different credentials.

Example usage:

```
Add-AzureAccount
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName '[NAME OF YOUR SUBSCRIPTION]'

$source = 'https://[STORAGEACCOUNTNAME].blob.core.windows.net/vhds/[VHDNAME].vhd'
$destination = 'f:\[VHDNAME].vhd'

Save-AzureVhd -Source $source -LocalFilePath $destination -NumberOfThreads 4
```