# Will my files will be lost if I stop and restart my Microsoft Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

Will my files and database will be lost if I stop or restart or my VM get crashed certainly. 
Can the files created at VM be stored in my computer hard disk so that I can retrieve them in future, if I need.

Comment: If you restart your VM it should maintain all of the files on it.

Comment: What about if VM got crashed somehow?

Comment: And you can download the VHD from Blob storage to your local hard disk.

Comment: How is these VHD files created??

Comment: It was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627658/download-vhd-image-from-azure-to-local-machine

Comment: Thank you. And what about my Linux VM got crashed suddenly. Then how will I retrieve back my files at that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your VM get crashed you will not be able to access your VM as well as your data but that doesn't mean you will loss your data. Your data will be stored there in the blob storage.

What you need to do is- attach the blob storage properly to some other vm or new vm to access it again.

Comment: Thank you. But how to- "attach the blob storage properly to some other vm or new vm to access it again."

Comment: This link can help you.-                                              https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495298.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned this was answered on another thread, the best thing to do is to download the VHD locally.

From the Windows Azure Portal you can easily download the VHD. Just navigate to STORAGE and then the storage account in which your virtual disk is created. Select CONTAINERS (at the top), open the container named "vhds". Just click the vhd you want and select DOWNLOAD (at the bottom of the page).

Have a great day

Comment: Thank you. I downloaded the .vhd file. Now I created a new VM machine /server and want to deploy my data of .vhd file.  How to do that ?